# Trying to update a single item's quantity when an item is "purchased" from my store, but every item in my table is updated. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

Please understand- I am not experienced with PHP. But I know I am close to figuring this out.

I have a table, generated by a while loop (getting data from a MySQL database), that gives the customer a list of albums from an artist. I want the customer to be able to input the quantity of the album they wish to purchase, and have the database update appropriately. I can get the code to loop through and update every album in my table (based on user input), but that is obviously not what I want. How can I make it so only ONE album is updated at a time??

Here is my code:

```
<div id = "MusicSearch"><h4>Search For Music</h4></div>
<div id="search">
<form  method="post" action="get-records.php?go"  id="searchform"> 
<input  type="text" name="artistName"> 
<input  type="submit" name="submit-form" value="Search"> 
</div>
<?php 

     if(isset($_POST['submit-form'])){ 
        $artistName = $_POST['artistName'];
     if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
     if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]+/", $_POST['artistName'])){

      include 'include/connect.php';

     $sql = "
SELECT y.artistName
     , x.albumName
     , x.albumID
     , x.cost
     , x.stock 
  FROM album x
  JOIN artist y
    ON x.artistID = y.artistID 
 WHERE y.artistName LIKE '%" .$artistName. "%'
";

     $result = $con->query($sql);

     echo '<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Album</th><th>Cost</th><th>Stock</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>'; 
    ?>  

    <?php    
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 

            $albumName=$row['albumName'];
            $cost=$row['cost'];
            //$albumID=$row['albumID'];
            $stock=$row['stock'];

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $artistName . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $albumName . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $cost . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $stock . '</td>';
        ?>
            <td><form method="post" action="get-records.php">
                  <input type="hidden" name="albumID[<?php  echo $row['albumID']; ?>]" value="<? echo $row['albumID']; ?>"></input> 
                  <input type="number" name="quantity[<?php  echo $row['albumID']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>"></input> 
                 <input  type="submit" name="purchase-form" value="Purchase"/></form></td>       

    <?php

    }
    echo "</table>"; 

        }
    } 
}   

      if(isset($_POST['quantity'])){

      foreach($_POST['albumID'] as $key => $id){  

        $quan = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['quantity'][$key]);

         $q = "UPDATE album SET stock = stock-$quan WHERE albumID = albumID"; 


    try{
        $result = $con->query($q);  

        if (!$result) 
        echo "Error, try again " . mysqli_error($con);

        if(is_null('id'))
        throw new Exception('Error. Try again');
    }
      catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo '<div class="error">' . $ex->getMessage() . '</div>';
    }                      

    }
  }  
?>
```

Comment: It seems pretty clear that `WHERE albumid = albumid` is wrong. Note that the beauty of this API is that it affords the use of parametrised and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry I know it is wrong, but that is the only thing I can get to work. When I try to put `WHERE albumID = $id` I get a cryptic error message telling me: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your update query with this `UPDATE album SET stock = 'stock-".$quan."' WHERE albumID = '".$id."'`

Comment: I get this error when I do that:  `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'albumID']; ?>'' at line 1`

Comment: yes I did. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what else to tell you. The error I am getting is not helpful at all.

Comment: Try  stock = '".$quan."' instead of stock = 'stock-".$quan."'

Comment: the same unhelpful error appears: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1`

Comment: Is your column name is correct ? because i tried this query just now and it worked perfactly

Comment: Make sure you are getting value of $id and $quan

Comment: thank you for being kind enough to trouble shoot with me. It works. You were correct, but for whatever reason I had to make it look like this: `$q = "UPDATE album SET stock = stock-'$quan' WHERE albumID = '$key'";`

Answer (score 1):

May you need to use `$_POST['albumID']`'s value Instead of `albumID`, here

```
$q = "UPDATE album SET stock = stock-$quan WHERE albumID = $id";
```

`albumID = albumID` is true for all rows that's why its updating all records

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried that, and I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @ferrari3000 : share your error, also value of `print_r($_POST['albumID'])` and what is you input value for `albumID` ?

Comment: That is all I am getting for the error message. The value for `print_r($_POST['albumID'])` is `Array ( [7] => ) ` I am getting that value from my own id value, generated in my MySQL table. 

`albumID` is already generated by MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You were also correct. As I told Sweta Parmar, the final code that worked was this: `$q = "UPDATE album SET stock = stock-'$quan' WHERE albumID = '$key'";`